# Join and derive relation when more than single column has foreign key reference to another table

Tags: sql

I have table role_relations where columns are referencing same another table called 'roles'. Currently i'm joining twice. Is there better way where join once and derive 'name' ?

```
SELECT r1.name, r2.name FROM role_relations rr
JOIN roles r1 ON rr.id = r1.id
JOIN roles r2 ON rr.parent_id = r2.id
WHERE rr.role_relation_id = :rrId;
```

Comment: This is just a method for the case. In both Oracle and Sql Server which are two different RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal if you have hierarchy data to need to join the definitions twice. I doubt you have performance issues, as it's common for security hierarchy (roles, groups) to perform such queries and basically the data is not huge (you have certain number of roles, not billions of them).

If you are concern about the double read of the data you can read the `role_relations` and `roles` once and build the output in the application.